# svn: E175002: GET request returned unexpected delta base

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, freebsd

Any clue how to debug or find cause of problem in title?

Scenario: One of the users commit files to SVN repository(server on freebsd/apache dav/) using tortutisesvn(windows 8.1). Files he uploads cannot be checkout on bsd machines(subversion-1.9.5) resulting:

```
svn: E175002: GET request returned unexpected delta base:
```

When I try to checkout code on ubuntu(windows shell) or windows it works fine. Also websvn works fine without problems on the same bsd machine.

Problem affects text files and images.

```
$svnadmin info /home/svn/myproject
Path: /home/svn/myproject
UUID: c022eb3e-090d-46c0-a7e1-d52c6120b926
Repository Format: 5
Compatible With Version: 1.9.0
Repository Capability: mergeinfo
Filesystem Type: fsfs
Filesystem Format: 7
FSFS Sharded: yes
FSFS Shard Size: 1000
FSFS Shards Packed: 0/0
FSFS Logical Addressing: no
Configuration File: /home/svn/myproject/db/fsfs.conf
```

Apache DAV gives:

```
 [ssl:info] (32)Broken pipe: AH01993: SSL output filter write failed.
 [dav:error]  Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]
 [dav:error]  A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #32]
 [dav:error]  Broken pipe  [500, #32]
```

Is it possible to inspect traffic or get more about this error code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please read more here: 
https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#serf-skelta-default

Apache `dav_svn_module directive` - bulk or skelta - set to 
`SVNAllowBulkUpdates Prefer`, to work with old and new clients

Answer (score 2):

Please read the settings - are the UTF8 tick boxes enabled?

https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseMerge_en/tmerge-dug-settings.html

Comment: also take note on the line ending settings

Comment: this make sense for text files but not sure if solve problem with images where you do not have control of utf8....